# How to fix cups?

Tags: printing

[image: error]

[image: Image2]

It's says that I don't have cups, I've already installed it. I need cups for my hp laserjet m277dw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `cups-daemon` package to get `cups.service`. CUPS is a client-server application. You just have the client, you need the server. Once you have the `cups-server`, you can administer CUPS with a browser, at `http://localhost:631`. There are multiple parts to CUPS. On my working Ubuntu 16.04.1 system (YMMV):

```
                  These are the cups* packages I have installed
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -l cups\* | egrep -v '^un'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-==============================================================================
ii  cups                                 2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD/driver support, web interface
ii  cups-browsed                         1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1        amd64                   OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - cups-browsed
ii  cups-bsd                             2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - BSD commands
ii  cups-client                          2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - client programs (SysV)
ii  cups-common                          2.1.3-4                 all                     Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - common files
ii  cups-core-drivers                    2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD-less printing
ii  cups-daemon                          2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - daemon
ii  cups-driver-gutenprint               5.2.10~pre2-0ubuntu2    all                     transitional dummy package for gutenprint printer driver
ii  cups-filters                         1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1        amd64                   OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Main Package
ii  cups-filters-core-drivers            1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1        amd64                   OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - PPD-less printing
ii  cups-pdf                             2.6.1-21                amd64                   PDF writer backend for CUPS (dummy transitional package)
ii  cups-pk-helper                       0.2.5-2ubuntu2          amd64                   PolicyKit helper to configure cups with fine-grained privileges
ii  cups-ppdc                            2.1.3-4                 amd64                   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation utilities
ii  cups-server-common                   2.1.3-4                 all                     Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - server common files


w3@aardvark:~(0)$ pgrep cupsd
7705
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ps -fp7705
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      7705     1  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
```